# Join Two MySQL queries horizontally. Keep all columns intact

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT * 
FROM Under_200 u
WHERE u.Chance_of_Gain_under > 75;


SELECT * 
FROM Over_200 o
WHERE o.Chance_of_Gain_over > 75;
```

I am trying to join two separate MySQL queries in a horizontal fashion. Such as a Pandas concat where the axis = 1.

Comment: Are you looking for a `UNION`?

Comment: I am looking for a join but I want to use the WHERE clauses for each separate table.

Comment: Could you add some information of your table structure to your question? By just seeing two selects i can't tell on which column(s) to join the tables.

Comment: I want to join the tables on the column Symbol. Both tables have the column table, and I want to filter each prior the join.

Answer (score 0):

If Symbol is the column denominator , you can use bith queries as subqueries

```
SELECT u.*,o.*
FROM
(SELECT * 
FROM Under_200 
WHERE Chance_of_Gain_under > 75) u
JOIN
(
SELECT * 
FROM Over_200 
WHERE Chance_of_Gain_over > 75)  o ON o.Symbol = u.Symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH custom_tab1
         AS (SELECT *
             FROM   under_200
             WHERE  chance_of_gain_under > 75),
         custom_tab2
         AS (SELECT *
             FROM   over_200
             WHERE  chance_of_gain_over > 75)
    SELECT *
    FROM   custom_tab1 ct1
           INNER JOIN custom_tab2 ct2
                   ON ct1.symbol = ct2.symbol;
```

Check if this works. I have solved using a common table expression.